# How to change the title and colour of a newly created a TabGroup in an Addon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a TagGroup and trying to update it:

```
//background.js

chrome.tabs.group({ tabIds: tabIds}, function (groupId) {

  //1
  // chrome.tabGroups.update(groupId, { title: groupTitle });

  //2
  // chrome.tabs.update(groupId, { collapsed: true, title: groupTitle });

   //3
   chrome.tabGroups.update(groupId, { title: groupTitle, color: "blue", collapsed: true });

  //...
```

For some reason, none of these functions will set title of a TagGroup, nor collapse the tabs into one.

How to do it then?

Comment: 1) Debug it in [devtools for the background script](/a/10258029). 2) It may be a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm 1) there's no error anywhere